# how to create finding elements web game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frameworks, game-physics

im trying to build a web game that display messy office room background and office elemnts on it and the user need to find those elements.
some thing like this:
http://www.games2rule.com/play/messy-office-room/9548

what is the right way to do it? any framework that can save me time?
should i use canvas or just simple divs with abosulte position that bind click events? for example create a main div that display the office bacgkround and for example laptop on it:

```
<div id="office-background">
    <div id="laptop"></div>
</div>
```

the #office-background will be position:relative and the laptop will be on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a background as you have described and a number of elements i.e. laptop, chair, printer desk as div. Then once these elements have been found drag and drop them in to a found basket which is another div.

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

This will allow you to do something with the elements rather than just the click makes it more interactive.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui      .css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
 </style>
 <script>
 $(function() {
 $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
   drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
   }
  });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
 <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```